# WooCommerce - Possible to gift (send) digital product to a friend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a simple ecommerce site for a friend who sells gift certificates online. I have decided to use WooCommerce as its free and is more than capable of what is required. As all his products are digital, I have already checked and found that Woocommerce supports digital products.

However I was unable to find if there was any option that allowed you to buy the certificate and enter a friends email so that they received the product as a gift via download link in email. Is there anyway to build this functionality into woocommrece? Is it possible to make it so that if a person checks the box to send it as a gift to a friend, they can write a custom message in the email that will be sent?

I understand this may be hard to do but if someone can provide me with a rough roadmap of how this would be done, it would be really good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WooCommerce is quite a bit lazy and you'll need to buy a plugin to do it. Smart Coupons and Gift Certificates Pro are plugins that let you do that. If your very smart in PHP + MySql, you might somehow be able to put it in.